# Java custom toString function error

Tags: java, class, oop, tostring

I'm trying to make a student class to take in and print some values about a student, but I get a "Invalid Method Declaration" error on line 29 and I have no idea why.

I am trying to contain student creation data inside one method, and a `tostring()` method in another method.

```
public class Student {

int ID;
int Age;
String Name;
double AvgLogin;


public Student(int ID,int Age,String Name,double AvgLogin)
{
    this.ID = ID;
    this.Age = Age;
    this.Name = Name;
    this.AvgLogin = AvgLogin;
}
public  printer(int ID,string Name,int Age,double AvgLogin) {
System.out.println("Age : " + Age + " Average Login time : " + AvgLogin + "ID :" + ID +" Name : " + Name);





} //end method

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public void setAge(int Age) {
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public double getAvgLogin() {
        return AvgLogin;
    }

    public void setAvgLogin(double AvgLogin) {
        this.AvgLogin = AvgLogin;
    }
}








//Student John = new Student(ID,Age,Name,AvgLogin)
```

Comment: Tip for new Java devs: Use your IDE to format your code (in Eclipse, Ctrl-Shift-F; IntelliJ: Ctrl+Alt+L). Not only will this help you spot mistakes like missing/extra brackets, it'll also make it less slightly likely that people reading your questions on SO will gauge their eyes out trying to make sense of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just missed the return type for your printer method. You should use the following code for your printer method.

```
public void printer(int ID,String Name,int Age,double AvgLogin) {
    System.out.println("Age : " + Age + " Average Login time : " + AvgLogin + "ID :" + ID +" Name : " + Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your method. One of them is lack of the return type. Second one is typing `string` instead of `String`. Thirdly, it looks nice if you start variable name from lower case. You should also format code before making a question.

```
    public void printer(int id, String name, int age, double avgLogin) {
        System.out.println("Age: " + age + ", average login time: " + avgLogin + ", ID: " + id + ", name: " + name);
    }
```